# Debugging Closure-compiler Compiled Javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo, google-closure-compiler

I have a complex dojo app that works correctly uncompiled, but after compiling with Google's [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), I get subtle differences in some behaviours.

As it is, it's exceedingly difficult to debug, and I've been unable to find any information about possible functional differences between compiled and uncompiled Javascript with Google Closure.

Can anyone point me in the direction of known differences, or share any similar experiences and some ideas of where to start looking?

Comment: No clue. But you may want to give UglifyJS a shot. I'm a big fan.

Comment: @AlexWayne Definitely want to keep Closure - the dojo build system works particularly well with it.

Comment: What optimization level are you using?
You can read about some limitations of the closure compiler here: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations

Comment: @Bart SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS - there are no `with` statements in the code base, and a single `eval` that is trivial and definitely unrelated to the bug I'm seeing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## General Closure Compiler Debugging Tips

- Use the `VERBOSE` warning level. This turns on all of the checks.
- Use the `debug` flag. It makes renamed symbols ridiculously long, but they are named in such a way you can find the original. If code works with the `debug` flag but not without it, it is almost certainly a renaming issue.
- Definitely use `formatting=PRETTY_PRINT`. Debugging compacted code is painful without it.
- Use [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)
- Disable the type based optimizations with `--use_types_for_optimization false`. Incorrect type annotations can cause the compiler to make invalid assumptions.

*UPDATE: As of the 20150315 compiler release, the type based optimizations are enabled by default.*

Comment: Thanks Chad, found the issue with this help, see my additional answer :D

Comment: source maps in chrome are fun too

Comment: I always forget about source maps - added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Chad's answer, I found a bug where my working code like so:

```
a = [b, b = a][0]; // swap variable values
```

Was compiled to:

```
a = b;
```

It might be fixed in later versions, because tests with the online Closure compiler app don't demonstrate the same bug. Fixed it by not trying to be clever, and using a 3rd variable to hold the old value while swapping values.

Comment: I can't find the exact issue that would have fixed this, but I'll bring it up and make sure. If not, we'll definitely take a look at this.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! I'll see if I can put together a replicating case for you, with version.

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems that I've seen with dojo 1.3 (pre-closure):

- If you have a class property named class it needs to be quoted. So {class: "css"} needs to be written as {"class": "css"} this includes any widget fields.
- Make sure you remove any debugger statements.