# Is it possible to compile WebDriverJS without minimizing the code by Google Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-closure-compiler

I need to modify [WebDriverJS](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Working_in_a_Browser) for my purposes. The compiled source is giving me a hard time debugging, though. Describing function names and comments would help me out big time! So I was wondering whether it is possible to compile WebDriverJS without minimizing it's content.

The `build.desc` for the JavaScript compilation is using [js_binary](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/CrazyFunBuild#js_binary) which is using Google Closure Compiler. Anyone of you know how to compile it and preserve functionnames and comments? This would rather be a merge of all sources then a compilation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Potential differences between compiled and uncompiled Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147479/potential-differences-between-compiled-and-uncompiled-javascript)

Comment: thanks... it's not really a complete Answer to my question but it brought me to the flags... can't belive I forgot to check those... --compilation_level=WHITESPACE_ONLY helps a lot, too. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Chads Post in ["Potential differences between compiled and uncompiled Javascript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147479/potential-differences-between-compiled-and-uncompiled-javascript) I've taken a deeper look at the [flags of closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref).

- `--compilation_level=WHITESPACE_ONLY` preserves function and variable names
- `--formatting=PRETTY_PRINT` doesn't remove linebreaks
- `--formatting=PRINT_INPUT_DELIMETER` gives me a better overview in which file to search for the source

Unfortunately I still couldn't figure out how to save the comments, but thats just a small problem since I can look them up in the source code.

**Update:**
Seems like the compilation_level doesn't remove the goog.required-calls. I've got to remove them somehow, because the script doesn't work with them.

**Update 2:**
I've removed all `goog.require($mod)` and `goog.provide($mod)` calls and defined Objects where needed (typically to find right after the `// Input $int` comments). It's working now.

Comment: Typically, you'd use the same optimization level you would on your live version. Using the `--debug` flags mangles the names in such a way that it's pretty easy to match up to the original source.

Comment: thank you! I tried that but I didn't like it, I've already made it work ;) I will edit the source files anyways when I figured out what is missing.