# closure compiler and closure inspector

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I am reading an old book on google closure and it tells me about debugging code using closure inspector. The following page tells me that it's depreciated:

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/inspector

It does not say what to use instead though. Is it depreciated without an alternative? If that's the case it's not depreciated it's cancelled and there is no way to debug closure compiled code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closure-inspector is now obsolete as you so noted. The replacement is that source maps are now supported natively in Chrome.

See my answer here for how to debug compiled code: [Debugging Closure-compiler Compiled Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147479/potential-differences-between-compiled-and-uncompiled-javascript/14147795#14147795)

Comment: Thank you Chad, I must have missed that on the google documents or maybe they forgot to put it in there.