# Force closure compiler to preserve source line feeds

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Google closure compiler removes all line feeds in advance mode. The `PRETTY_PRINT` option format the output again and `PRINT_INPUT_DELIMITER` does nothing.

Is there  any way to force it to keep all line feeds exactly like the source JS file so it's possible to trace errors easier?

Comment: I think you really should be asking how to debug compiled javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147479/debugging-closure-compiler-compiled-javascript/14147795#14147795

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth thank you for your hint, but I would see this as an option!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think closure compiler does raw concatenation. But Closure-annotated code can just be executed directly in the browser - I usually set up my server to serve the raw files concatenated together.

Comment: Closure-compiler is a compiler. Line feeds aren't represented in the syntax tree - preserving them isn't ever going to be an option.